# Problem with background images and bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am trying to create a responsive layout for an eshop (for clothes). I must use Bootstrap 3 and the images of the products must be inline style background images to a container. I have big problem when I try to style the containers and images in order to have a good result in mobile devices.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well.. this is not really a question, add details of what's that big problem and what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.please add the code as well. or image.  However, for mobile responsive, you can try col-md. / col-sm as per the requirement. refer this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/